# Excel Pivot: make 1-dimensonal data 2-dimensional

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel table with a structure as follows

```
Customer1 Domain1 Domain2 Product1
...
Customer1 Domain1 Domain2 ProductN
Customer1 Domain2 Domain3 Attribute1
...
Customer1 Domain2 Domain3 AttributeN
...
CustomerN Domain1 Domain2 Product1
...
CustomerN Domain1 Domain2 ProductN
CustomerN Domain2 Domain3 Attribute1
...
CustomerN Domain2 Domain3 AttributeN
```

Customer and Domain are a fixed set of data, <20 differen item per column. Product and Attribute contain flexible data. The table is >1000 rows. As you can see, the data mixes different kind of information per column.

I would like to build a 2-dimensional table, linking the data with the Domain2 attribute, preferably using Excel's pivot features, as follows:

```
         Attribute1 ... AttributeN
Product1
...          (Count of Domain2)
ProductN
```

I would be OK with transforming the data into a different structure if needed.

Is that possible in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to create a pivot report if Product and Attribute are in the same column. If these are different properties of a line item they do not BELONG in the same column. You need to change your source data to a model that properly reflects the properties of a line item. Product and Attribute are two different things and need to be placed in two different columns if you want to use one in the rows and the other in the column of a pivot table.

This is about data architecture more than about Excel and pivot tables.